# Prime of the form $n=kp^2+1$

Tags: prime-numbers

If p is a prime and k is a positive number less than p, 
and $2^k$ is incongruent to 1, $2^{(n-1)}$ is congruent to 1,
then $kp^2+1$ would be a prime number?

Comment: Firstly, no formula as simple as that always produces primes. Secondly, it's not clear what you mean by "congruent to 1" and "incongruent to 1" since you do not specify modulo what. Thirdly, you give no reason to believe this is true.

Comment: If your $n$ in the question is the same $n$ as the title, then $2^{n-1} = 2^{k(p^2)} \equiv 2^{k} \mod{p}$, so unless congruence is similar to flammable, it can't be congruent and incongruent to 1. 

Comment: He probably means congruences modulo $n$, so one of his conditions is that $n$ is a base $2$ pseudoprime, if not prime. Here is a list of all such numbers up to $10^{15}$: http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/Pseudoprimes/
If there is no counterexample to his conjecture on this list, then it gets interesting. 

Comment: Also posted to math.stackexchange, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150853/prime-of-the-form-kp21, without any mention of the post here. 

Comment: @Felipe, I verified that no counterexamples exist in this list.

Comment: It's badly stated, unmotivated, rudely crossposted, and shows no sign of work on the part of OP --- but it **is** a real question!

Answer (score 0):

I think that he omitted "modulo n".
 I tried to solve this problem with the fact :
 $ord_n{2}$ divides $n-1=kp^2$,
 and thought that his conjecture is true.
 But I couldn't proved it.